# AWS Amplify API with GraphQL access rules defined but not working

Tags: flutter, graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

I'm using AWS Amplify API with GraphQL in my Flutter app and I have defined a GraphQL schema with the following access rules:

- Any user, authenticated or not, can read all UserProfiles.
- Only the owner can create, read, update, and delete their own UserProfile.

I am authenticating users with amplify_auth_cognito using Email.

This is the schema

```
type UserProfile @model @auth(rules: [
   { allow: public, operations: [read]}, 
   { allow: owner } ]) {
  content: String
}
```

Currently

Authenticated user can create the user profile but they can only read the one that they have created themselves

Authenticated users can't read any other user profile created by another user

When Unauthenticated users try to read the data I get the following message in visual studio,

```
Query failed: UnknownException {
  "message": "unable to send GraphQLRequest to client.",
   "underlyingException": "SignedOutException {\n  \"message\": \"No user is currently signed in\"\n}"
 }
```

This how i create a UserProfile and it is saving in the backend,

```
Future<void> createUserProfile() async {
  try {
    final user = UserProfile(content: nameController.text);
    final request = ModelMutations.create(user);
    final response = await Amplify.API.mutate(request: request).response;

    final createdUserProfile = response.data;
    if (createdUserProfile == null) {
      safePrint('errors: ${response.errors}');
      return;
    }
    safePrint('Mutation result: ${createdUserProfile.content}');
  } on ApiException catch (e) {
    safePrint('Mutation failed: $e');
  }
}
```

this is how i read a UserProfile,

```
Future<List<UserProfile?>> queryUserProfile() async {
  try {
    final request = ModelQueries.list(UserProfile.classType);
    final response = await Amplify.API.query(request: request).response;

    final userProfiles = response.data?.items;
    if (userProfiles == null) {
      safePrint('errors: ${response.errors}');
      return const [];
    }
    print(userProfiles);
    return userProfiles;
  } on ApiException catch (e) {
    safePrint('Query failed: $e');
    return const [];
  }
}
```

I know when trying to read as an Unauthenticated user the error that is printed out is something to do with SignedOutException
but i thought that public rule i set means i don't need to be signed in as a user

I'm a very new at AWS Amplify and Flutter any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do unauthenticated users have an IAM role available?

Comment: When i was setting the project up in VS code when going through amplify add API i added Cognito users pools then IAM role when doing the set up in terminal but not sure if i need to do something else  thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

the exception you have is because of an unauthenticated session, the possibility is you may select IAM or Cognito_user_POOl as auth mode and that expired after some time depending upon your pool settings and that's why you are getting this exception on your GRAPHQL queries.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an authenticator.

You can follow this tutorial: https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/flutter/connected-components/authenticator

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)